# Wi-Fi (DW1820A) not working on macOS when rebooting immediatly from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers

I am having a weird issue. I am dual booting macOS Catalina with Ubuntu, and when I'm on Linux and then restart directly to macOS, the Wi-Fi is not working (greyed and no Wi-Fi detected), so I have to either restart it one more time or put it to sleep mode and wake it up to make the Wi-Fi work again (or if i want to switch directly from Linux to macOS I have to shutdown and then start again and boot to macOS).

My Wi-Fi card is DW1820A, it works perfectly on each OS, I only have this issue which is annoying since i switch a lot between those two OSs. when I reboot from macOs to Linux Wi-Fi works normally, so the problem is obviously with Linux (I think Wi-Fi adapters don't completely power off when rebooting).

Comment: The problem is obviously with MacOS ;-) It works on Ubuntu, but doesn't on MacOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am triple booting with Windows as well, and when i restart from Windows to MacOS, there is no problem, this only happens when i go from Linux to MacOS.